# Specify container names of a Docker Swarm service with naming scheme

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

How can I specify the names of the containers created by a service?

I know I can use naming templates with hostname for example:

```
Docker service create –name serviceName –replicas 2 –network skynet  
--hostname=”{{.Node.Hostname}}-{{.Task.Slot}}” imageName
```

This creates tidy hostnames for my containers,
but can I achieve the same with the regular container names?

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you need this?

Comment: I find it useful for testing purposes. If I want to test connectivity between two microservices on different hosts, I can just ping the container name from within another container... Unless that container name is gibberish.

Comment: but you can use the service's name

Comment: to ping a service you can use its name,
for example, if you have a microservice A and a microservice B and you want to test connectivity between these 2 microservices that are on the same swarm network you can simply use the server name and docker swarm will resolve the host by itself.
ping serviceName